# vim block highlight doesn't work right in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.3684.101, built on July 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13

#

This happens on windows and mac and on older versions too and its super frustrating. The block select of the vim plugin doesn't work right.

I go into block select mode and highlight stuff:

[image]

I go into insert mode, write some characters and exit and look at what it does:

[image]

This is driving me nuts! It doesn't insert in all the highlighted lines i can't stand it.

This must have something to do with intellij's bracket awareness because if I highlight a block of unindented text with no formatting it works, like this:

[image]

And if I insert and edit and exit it works:

[image]

I have no .ideavimrc so its not my own settings. If this isn't a bug, how to get it to work?

Comment: What exactly do you type after selecting your text using `<C-V>`? For me it works as expected if I select several first characters of each line of several methods and then write `I`, `//`, `<Esc>`.

Comment: Yup after `<C-V>` I type `I` then in insert mode `//` and then i escape with `<C-{>`. Its work for you for bracketed text?

Comment: Oh another thing that might not be obvious from the screen shot is I'm not selectively highlighting just the method blocks, Im just doing block select and moving the cursor down.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it works for me. Could you please clarify what exactly is wrong on your screenshots? An example with an actual text might be easier to get and reproduce.